# Maximise output issue

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization

When I execute the following command, I get a numerical output as follows:

```
In[28]:= Maximize[{n^3, n^3 <= 3110400000000}, n, Integers]

Out[28]= {3110217954173, {n -> 14597}}
```

But if I change the function to maximise as follows:

```
In[30]:= Maximize[{n^2, n^2 <= 3110400000000}, n, Integers]

Out[30]= Maximize[{n^2, n^2 <= 3110400000000}, n, Integers]
```

Why do I not get an answer for $n$ in the latter case?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug, that manifests because of the fact that the answer could be positive or negative. If you look at the `Trace` of this operation, with `TraceInternal -> True`, you can see that it gets as far as finding the answer as a rounded version of $\pm720000\sqrt{6}$. It has candidate solutions of either `Ceiling[-720000 Sqrt[6]]` or `Floor[720000 Sqrt[6]]`.

The following logic appears to assume (and, as I am only looking at the trace, I could be mistaken) that the final answer will be a unique integer within the bounds defined by the ceiling and the floor of the unconstrained expression. So, it attempts

```
Reduce[Element[n, Integers] && -1763632 <= n <= 1763632]
```

which of course does not produce the sought-after single value of `n`. It does work for `n^3`, however, because the two possible values are both positive.

Interestingly, completely different (and more complicated) logic is followed in the case of `n^4`, which manages to give the correct answer (or rather, one of the two possible correct answers; the negative one). I am still not too sure if the argument in this case is completely solid, because eventually it gets into the situation of looking at only negative solutions, apparently by accident after being a bit careless about multi-valued roots. However, this does result in producing a viable solution.

The reasoning behind `Minimize` seems a little obscure, not least because constraining `n` to be positive does not seem to bring out the correct behavior. So, I hope that someone else will be able to shed further light on the problem.

Comment: I am not sure if the existence of a positive and negative answer is the source. It works well with smaller numbers.  `Maximize[{n^2, n^2 <= 10}, n, Integers]` and  `Maximize[{n^3, n^3 <= 10}, n, Integers]` give correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure, but I think it is happening because of a poor starting point (probably coming from the default algorithm) which is not giving any convergence. As a result Mathematica is giving the only possible output - the input itself.

A possible alternative can be defining a starting point with `FindMaximum`

```
FindMaximum[{n^2, n^2 <= 3110400000000}, {n, 300}]
```

Here I told Mathematica to look around/from `n=300` (you can choose any other value) and it gives me

> {$3.1104 \times 10^{12}$, {$n \rightarrow 1.76363 \times 10^6$}}

(with a warning about convergence).

Comment: What poor starting point? `Maximize` works symbolically.

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrR for pointing that out. Sorry for the mistake